# Removing the $ in first part of the data

Tags: perl

I have a string

```
my $string = $14.275; ##   where i need to remove the $
```

I have tried by using the below code

```
 $y = substr($string , 1, index($string));
```

The output should be 14.275

Comment: You will need quotes on the initialization.

Comment: If the dollar sign will always be there, `substr($string, 1)` will suffice. A better transformation would probably be `$string =~ s/^\$//;`

Answer (score 0):

First quotes string value and write code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = '$14.275';
$string =~ s/^\$//;
print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
14.275
```